# ERROR: The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.3.10 and higher

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle

I got the following error when i am using "flutter_launch 0.2.0" in my code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_launch/flutter_launch.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => new _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  void whatsAppOpen() async {
    await FlutterLaunch.launchWathsApp(phone: "5534992016545", message: "Hello");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text('Plugin example app'),
        ),
        body: new Center(
          child: FlatButton(
            child: Text("Open WhatsApp"),
            onPressed: () {
              whatsAppOpen();
            },
          )
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.3.10 and higher.
  The following dependencies do not satisfy the required version:
  project ':flutter_launch' -> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.2.71
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

My Kotlin class is this

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.10'
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
}
```

}

please tell me why this happen.

Answer (score 0):

- Upgrade **`kotlin-gradle-plugin`** Version
- Upgrade **`build:gradle`** Version

**DEMO**

```
 buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.72'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
    }
  }
```

And open **`gradle-wrapper.properties`** and upgrade gradle version.

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.4-all.zip
```

Comment: The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.3.10 and higher.
The following dependencies do not satisfy the required version:
project ':flutter_launch' -> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.2.71
@IntelliJ Amiya same problem